# Combining Date Schedules into 1 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope you can help me with this.

I have this table that has multiple rows for date

[image]

My Question is how do I merge the following Date columns into one, identifying it a "date" column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like BigQuery question! In any case  - check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to accomplish is called *unpivot*.

Comment: Hi, yes this is exactly what im looking for. I guess im looking for alternatives as we dont have unpivot defined in our internal tool.